# Help! Dropped computer! Grub showing up! How to bring back Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, data-recovery, grubrescue

I am running a dual boot win8 and Ubuntu 14.04 on a qosmio x875. I had my laptop in my backpack and the backpack fell out of my car. When I opened it much later I found that one of the back plates was slightly open (I lost a screw while fiddling with it long ago). I figured it hadnt opened far enough to do real damage (its a pretty tough computer). I then tried turning ir on. Got the ubuntu login screen. Couldnt log me in and froze with some weird plain text pop up of all squares. So i tried restarting it manually (power button). I get a grub bootloading screen. I've tried inputting exit and this takes me to a sort of bios in terms of where to access first. When I try to get into ubuntu it fails and goes back to grub. I can access windows just fine. I tried booting from the USB drive with my copy of ubuntu and that does not seem to be working. Any suggestions to bring back my beloved operating system?

Update: good news. It appears I was able to get the USB working by simply rebooting from the BIOS. At least temporarily but when I checked disk for defects I got 2 file errors (but no elaboration on what they were exactly) should I try reinstalling? What should be my next course of action?

Update 2: So I went into windows to look at the partition set up. Since I have two drives, one specifically for windows, one for Linux, I figured the both of them will pop up. I can't find the second drive in the partitions on windows...this looks bad.

Comment: Try not to use the computer too much, and get it to a qualified computer repairer (you might be able to return it to the supplier or manufacturer if you contact them and ask first). This sounds very much like a hardware issue, probably with the hard drive but it could be something else. The less you use the hard disk the easier it is to recover data from it.

Comment: Not really an option atm, I have work I need done. I'm confident in my abilities to if not fix it, at least recover the data. I just need to know the steps.

Comment: Depends, I have had almost the exact same problem (computer broke (due to design fault with hinge), needed to get work done) - my fix worked and allowed me to use the laptop for the next few months, the problem is getting repaired now might be much more expensive due to that. Currently typing on its replacement.

Comment: So you're saying that a quick fix might shorten the life of the computer and because of that it may be best to hold off?

Comment: Also. Since I have two drives in this computer (one for Linux, the other for Windows), if I only use the Windows drive, will that affect the Linux drive still? Does the heat factor in?

Comment: did you do a badblocks check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the specs, the qosmio x875 has the option of a 2nd disk, which I assume you have (not just a single drive partitioned for Windows and Linux). The fact that the system booted to Ubuntu initially indicates the Linux drive isn't (or wasn't) dead.

The only (normal) Windows program which would acknowledge the Linux drive would be Disk Management (usually in Computer Management) which should show it as Disk1, but with partitions of type 'Unknown'. It won't show in Explorer at all. If it doesn't show in Disk Management, then it's possible the drive has come loose. I used to have an Acer 8920G laptop with 2 drives and the drive bay cover had protrusions which held the drives in place. If your laptop is similar and the cover is loose, it's possible the drive has slipped slightly away from it's connector. I assume you have previously opened the cover and can check this; simply make sure both drives are firmly pushed into their connectors.

In normal operation, both drives are running whether you're in Linux or Windows, so using the laptop in Windows shouldn't be a problem as long as the Linux drive is either fully in place or, obviously, completely removed. Before running it for too long, check the drive isn't loose as a partial connection could cause problems.

Good luck.

P.S. You need to get a replacement screw for the cover plate or see about rearranging the existing screws so it can't come open.

Comment: thanks for the help. Beginning the taking apart process now.

Comment: Yup that totally did it. Just had to slide it right back into place. Totally free fix. Thanks for the input.